# jvm crashes when trying to send TCHAR type to java function that accepts string as argument

Tags: java, c++, c, winapi, java-native-interface

While trying to send the name of the window on which currently a key is being pressed from a JNI C code to a java method jvm crashes. I think it is due to passing of an invalid argument. Please explain why the call fails and how can I send the argument ?

Prototype of  java method looks like :

```
public void storeNameOfForegroundWindow(String windowName) {
  // store in the list
}
```

*JNI C snippet :*

```
 jmethodID callBackToStoreWindowName = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"storeNameOfForegroundWindow","(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
 TCHAR title[500];
 GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow(), title, 500);
 jvalue windowName,*warr;
 windowName.l = title;
 warr = &title;
 (*Env)->CallVoidMethodA(Env,object,callBackToStoreWindowName,warr);
```

JVM crashes as it encounters the above snippet.I know that jvm crashes due to passing of  invalid argument to the java function ( via C code) . If that is so please explain how do I send the argument .I need to send the title of the current window to the java function.

Comment: `TCHAR` can be either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on your project settings. Which is it here?

Comment: @BoPersson I haven't set anything of the sort of TCHAR .

Answer (score 2):

Since your method has a String as its argument, you should give it a `jstring` instance. JVM can not understand what a `TCHAR` is. So you need to convert your chars to a java string using:

```
(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, title);
```

**EDIT**: if `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, i.e. is 16 bit and can be cast to a jchar, then you need to use `NewString` instead of `NewStringUTF`. You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: `NewStringUTF()` expects UTF-8 input, but `GetWindowText()` does not output UTF-8 text. Using the arrar as-is will only work if it contains ASCII characters only.  Otherwise, you will have to use `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP)` and `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8)` to convert to UTF-8.

Comment: how do I send `jstring` to the java function ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau _"...but GetWindowText() does not output UTF-8 text."_ what is the output then ?

Comment: @Y.E.P: the same way you do it now - pass it as a parameter to `CallVoidMethodA`.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy this is crashing the JVM

Comment: @RemyLebeau: yeah, I have no idea how winapi works, I'm just saying that the OP needs a jstring. Also, will `NewString` work with wchar, as I've added in my edit?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17976/discussion-between-y-e-p-and-denis-tulskiy)

Answer (score 0):

When I first see `TCHAR`, I say "Oh! It is magnificent, You can write one code that work in both Win9X and WinNT and also call best platform functions with just one definition: _UNICODE". But in time I see that this confuse many developers. There is nothing standalone as `TCHAR`, it is a typedef of char when `_UNICODE` is not defined and a typedef of `wchar_t` otherwise, so depending on project's definition it will change. But on the other hand Java method expect only one of them (either char or wchar_t, but I don't know which one of them), so if you define `_UNICODE` in your project (this will be done automatically in new IDE) and Java method expect a char* then you are passing a wchar_t* then you are passing a wrong type to the function and length of string will be counted as one (since wchar_t is 2 bytes, it map most of single byte char to char + an extra '\0') and if you pass a char* to function while it expect a wchar_t*, it may produce an error (for example access violation) because:

```
TCHAR title[500]; // will be converted to char title[500];
// now fill it and it may contain 'abcde\0 some junk data'
// Java want to interpret this as wchar_t* and expect '\0\0' as end of string
// since wchar_t is 2 byte and it may never see it in you string and read beyond
// end of title that is obviously an error!
```

Comment: Regardless of what `TCHAR` maps to, you cannot pass a `TCHAR[]` array directly to `jvalue`. It is expecting an allocated `jstring` instead, which you must allocate using one of the `NewString...()` methods of the JNI `Env` object. That is why the JVM crashes - it is receiving a pointer to memory that is not compatible with Java.